# Recursive function issue

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I'm working with a tree structure of Installation Places: each one may contain child InstallationPlaces and these can also contain children and so on and so on. I've got the following function:

```
public JsonResult GetInstPlacesTree()
{
    InstallationPlaceModel ipm = new InstallationPlaceModel();
    var dataContext = ipm.getRootInstallationPlaces();

    var instPlaces = from ip in dataContext.installationPlaces
                    select new
                    {
                        id = ip.installationPlace.id,
                        Name = ip.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
                    };

    return Json(instPlaces, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This function returns only the root level of the tree.

I have got two working methods:

- one returns the root Installation Places;
- the other returns the children of a given Installation Place;

They both return IEnumerable variables.

```
getRootInstallationPlaces();
getChildInstallationPlaces(id);
```

How can I achieve to call all the Installation Places and respective children?

I have tried this alternative to the `GetInstPlacesTree()` function:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> GetDefaultInlineData()
{
    InstallationPlaceModel ipm = new InstallationPlaceModel();
    List<TreeViewItemModel> fullTree = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();
    var gipo = ipm.getChildInstallationPlaces(currentInstallationPlace.InstallationPlaceId);
    List<TreeViewItemModel> childTree = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();
    if (gipo.installationPlaces.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (wsInstallationPlace.installationPlaceOutput child in gipo.installationPlaces)
        {
            TreeViewItemModel childTreeItem = new TreeViewItemModel
            {
                Text = child.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
                Id = child.installationPlace.id
            };
            childTree.Add(childTreeItem);
        }
    }
    TreeViewItemModel fatherTreeItem = new TreeViewItemModel
    {
        Text = currentInstallationPlace.InstallationPlaceMediumDescription,
        Id = currentInstallationPlace.InstallationPlaceId,
        Items = childTree
    };
    fullTree.Add(fatherTreeItem);
    return fullTree;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Before one can understand recursion, one has to understand recursion first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like the following should do what you are after. Essentially it keeps your initial method almost as-is but it populates the child `Items` of each top-level with a recursive call.

The recursive call grabs the children and adds each child to a `List<TreeViewItemModel>` to be returned but their children are in turn populated by a call to the recursive function. The recursion will end when there are no children left:

```
public JsonResult GetInstPlacesTree()
{
    InstallationPlaceModel ipm = new InstallationPlaceModel();
    var dataContext = ipm.getRootInstallationPlaces();

    var instPlaces = from ip in dataContext.installationPlaces
                        select new TreeViewItemModel 
                        {
                            id = ip.installationPlace.id,
                            Name = ip.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
                            Items = getChildInstallationPlacesRecursive(ip.installationPlace.id, ipm)
                        };

    return Json(instPlaces, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public List<TreeViewItemModel> getChildInstallationPlacesRecursive(int id, InstallationPlaceModel ipm)
{
    List<TreeViewItemModel> children = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();

    var gipo = ipm.getChildInstallationPlaces(id);

    foreach (wsInstallationPlace.installationPlaceOutput child in gipo.installationPlaces)
    {
        children.Add(new TreeViewItemModel
        {
            Text = child.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
            Id = child.installationPlace.id,
            Items = getChildInstallationPlacesRecursive(child.installationPlace.id, ipm)
        });
    }

    return children;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The result is a tree without any children. There are 3 root nodes but its children aren't there

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint on `var gipo = ipm.getChildInstallationPlaces(id);` - are there any results? The only thing I can think is I should have re-used `ipm` by passing it to `getChildInstallationPlacesRecursive`. Other than that I think the logic is correct. I'll update the code.

Comment: The gipo variable contains all the children of the installation place whose ID is passed as parameters. Those methods work perfectly. I'll try your updated code, thanks

Comment: I had to tweak it so it would serve my interests but your logic is indeed correct and led me to the solution. Thanks! +1, bounty and correct answer! By the way, isn't my question upvote worthy? ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could help @chiapa. As it happens I think your question is up vote worthy. +1. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To make it recursive, you have to think that child places are, at the same time, roots of their own childs, then you can call the same function for them.

```
private IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> RecursivePlaces(InstallationPlace root){
     var output = new List<TreeViewItemModel>();
     output.add(new TreeViewItemModel
        {
            Text = root.installationPlace.mediumDescription,
            Id = root.installationPlace.id
        });         

     foreach(var child in root.installationPlaces)
       output.AddRange(RecursivePlaces(child));

     return output;
}

//Initial call
RecursivePlaces(ipm.getRootInstallationPlace());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the concept and know that each place will be root of its children, I just want to adapt that to my current code. Unfortunately, your answer is theoretical, it doesn't solve my specific problem. It can't be applied like this

Comment: Could you explain more i depth what's the goal of your function? Is it to get a list of TreeViewItemModel?

Comment: Yes it is, I want to get a tree in that format, as you can see in my latter function

Comment: The problem is on the foreach cycle, because an installation place doesn't have installation places (`foreach(var child in root.installationPlaces)`). The only way to get child installation places is via the `getChildInstallationPlaces(id)` method. This isn't easy, I have been struggling for a while now

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this without recursion with following approach. I wrote it in some kind of pseudo-code, so you will get an idea what I suggest to accomplish, I didn't used your exact function names and structures and classes...

```
queue = new List<>();
queue.Add(initialInstallation);
retVal = new List<>();

while (queue.Count > 0) {
    retVal.Add(queue[0].GetData());
    queue.Add(queue[0].GetChildren());
    queue.Remove(0);
}

return retVal;
```